# Golang import local package failure

Tags: go

I am trying to import a local package (token) into a directory of a project, but when trying to build the Gateway subdirectory as seen below, I am always getting an error that the package cannot be found in the GOROOT directory

Here is what the directory structure looks like:

```
~goProjects/src
    -Project
        -Gateway
            -main.go
        -token
            -token.go
```

Within the Gateway subdirectory:

```
go build
package Project/token is not in GOROOT (/usr/local/go/src/Project/token)
```

This is how I am trying to import the local package "token" into my Gateway main.go file:

```
package main

import (
    "Project/token"
)
```

Here is my go env setup:

```
GO111MODULE=""
GOARCH="amd64"GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/home/nexxus/.cache/go-build"
GOENV="/home/nexxus/.config/go/env"GOEXE=""GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOINSECURE=""
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/nexxus/goProjects"
GOPRIVATE=""GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/linux_amd64"GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="gcc"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD=""
```

After reading a few posts on this including the how to write go code that I have seen referenced a few times, it seems like the compiler should be checking the GOPATH for packages as well as the GOROOT directory. It doesn't seem like my build process is looking at my GOPATH first, and is just checking the GOROOT, not finding the local package there, and exiting

I have compiled the token package successfully before trying to build the Gateway directory as well. Does anyone have suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why you're not using Go modules. It's much better and hassle-free. Just a go.mod on the top level and relative to the module name you give, you can import private packages.

Comment: Do your package name and package folder name match?

Comment: Read How to Write Go Code and _stick_ _to_ _it_. `Project/token` would be the import path of a package of the stdlib. Import it by its proper import name which starts with the module name.

Comment: Thank you @subhamSarkar, seems this has helped to solve the issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you are using Go 1.14 in which case GOPATH is not used (at least in the way you seem to expect) unless you turn off Go modules.

$ export GO111MODULE=off

But as @Subham Sarkar wisely suggests you should use Go modules.

$ go mod init Project

However, if this is anything more than a test you should not use the name "Project" but a name that won't clash such as "github.com/yourname/Project".

Comment: Yep the module seemed to do the trick, thank you all for your inputs